# How to import a function from another folder in the folder above

Tags: rust

My directory structure looks like this

```
src
├── main.rs
├── paas_core
│   ├── create.rs
│   └── mod.rs
└── rest_api
    ├── mod.rs
    └── rest.rs
```

I want to use a function declared in file `create.rs` in the file called `rest.rs`. I am trying to use the module in the rest_api module but I can not figure out how to do it.

I tried using `super::paas_core` in `rest.rs` but that didn't work.

Comment: using `super` within `rest.rs` would refer to the `rest_api` module. So you'd want `super::super::paas_core` or perhaps simpler, `crate::paas_core`.

Comment: @kmdreko I tried with crate as well but I get the error `no paas_core in root`

Comment: That would imply that you do not have `mod paas_core;` in `main.rs`.

Comment: @Herohtar, I clearly do...

Comment: No, you clearly don't -- that's exactly what the `no paas_core in root` message means: you haven't declared `paas_core` as a module within your `main.rs` file. But you haven't provided a [mcve] to show what you are doing, so beyond that, everyone has to guess at what your program looks like.

Comment: @Herohtar clearly from my directory structure you can see that paas_core exists. The way I solved this problem was by using `#[path = "../paas_core/create.rs"] mod paas_core;`.

Comment: `paas_core` exists, but you have to *tell Rust that it exists* by adding the line `mod paas_core` in your `main.rs` file, then you can `use crate::paas_core` or `use super::super::paas_core` in your `rest.rs` file. The answer posted by Benjamin shows a good example of this. The "solution" that you came up with using the `path` annotation will work, but it is wrong and it should not be done that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the file `rest_api/rest.rs` do you have to use `use crate::paas_core;` in order to be able to reference from rest_api to paas_core and `paas_core/mod.rs` need the statement `pub mod create;` to ensure you can call the function from rest_api directly using `paas_core::create::create_func();`

I hope it explains it. An full example might look like this:

file: main.rs

```
mod paas_core;
mod rest_api;

fn main() {
    rest_api::rest_func();
}
```

file: rest_api/mod.rs

```
mod rest;

pub fn rest_func() {
    println!("rest_func() in rest_api/mod.rs called!");
    rest::rest_caller();
}
```

file: rest_api/rest.rs

```
use crate::paas_core;
pub fn rest_caller() {
    println!("rest_caller() in rest_api/rest.rs called!");
    paas_core::create::create_func();
}
```

file: paas_core/mod.rs

```
pub mod create;
```

file: paas_core/create.rs

```
pub fn create_func() {
    println!("create_func() in paas_core/create.rs finally called!");
}
```

output if you are running it:

```
rest_func() in rest_api/mod.rs called!
rest_caller() in rest_api/rest.rs called!
create_func() in paas_core/create.rs finally called!
```